# How to loop through csv files in a directory and write values to a two dimensional list?

Tags: python

I am an absolute programming novice trying to work with some csv files.  Though what I am trying to do overall is more complex, I am currently stuck on this problem:

The csv files I have contain a fixed number of 'columns' and a variable number of rows.  What I want to do is open each csv file in a directory, while in memory store the files values to a 2d list, and then pull one 'column' of data from that list.  By doing this in a loop, I could append a list with one column of data from each csv file.

When I do this for a single file, it works:

```
csvFile = 'testdata.csv'
currentFile = csv.reader(open(csvFile), delimiter=';')
errorValues = []

    for data in currentFile:

        rows = [r for r in currentFile] #Store current csv file into a 2d list           
        errorColumn = [row[34] for row in rows] #Get position 34 of each row in 2D list
        errorColumn = filter(None, errorColumn) #Filter out empty strings
        errorValues.append(errorColumn) #Append one 'column' of data to overall list
```

When I try to loop it for all files in my directory, I get a 'list index out of range' error:

```
dirListing = os.listdir(os.getcwd())    
errorValues = []

for dataFile in dirListing:
    currentFile = csv.reader(open(dataFile), delimiter=';')        

    for data in currentFile:

        rows = [r for r in currentFile] #Store current csv file into a 2d list           
        errorColumn = [row[34] for row in rows] #Get position 34 of each row in 2D list
        errorColumn = filter(None, errorColumn) #Filter out empty strings
        errorValues.append(errorColumn) #Append one 'column' of data to overall list

    errorColumn = [] #Clear out errorColumn for next iteration
```

The error occurs at 'errorColumn = [row[34] for row in rows]'. I have tried all sorts of ways to do this, always failing to an index out of range error.  The fault is not with my csv files as I have used the working script to test them one by one.  What could be the problem?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You loop over `currentFile` then loop over `currentFile` inside the loop again? That will not do what you expect it to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop goes through the lines of the CSV file. Each line is converted to the row of element by the reader. This way, the `data` in the loop is already the row. The next construct also iterates through the open file. This is wrong.

There is a problem with your `open()`. The file must be opened in binary mode (in Python 2).

Try the following (I did not put everything you wanted inside):

```
dirListing = os.listdir(os.getcwd())    
errorValues = []

rows = []                  # empty array of rows initially

for fname in dirListing:
    f = open(fname, 'rb')  # open in binary mode (see the doc)
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')        

    errorColumn = []       # initialized for the file

    for row in reader:
        rows.append(row) #Store current csv file into a 2d list           
        if len(row) > 34:
            errorColumn.append(row[34]) #Get position 34 of each row in 2D list

    errorValues.append(errorColumn)

    f.close()              # you should always close your files
```

Beware! The `os.listdir()` returns also the names of subdirectories. Try to add

```
if os.path.isfile(fname):
    ...
```

By the way, you should clearly describe what is your actual goal. There may be a better way to solve it. You may be mentally fixed to the solution that came first to your mind. Take advantage of this media to have more eyes and more headst to suggest the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  This does almost exactly what I wanted to do in the first place.  It looks like I still have a lot to learn about the simple things in python.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit surprised that the error you mention is at the `[r for r in currentFile]`. At worst, your `rows` list would be empty...

Are you 100% sure **all** your lines have at least 35 columns ? That you don't have an empty line somewhere ? At the very end ? It'd be worth checking whether

```
errorColumn = [row[34] for row in rows if row]
```

still gives an error. Provided that you got rid of the `for data in currentFile` line first (that you don't use and more important consumes your `currentFile`, leaving you with `rows==[]`)

Comment: Oof, I've made a silly mistake.  The error occurs at "errorColumn = [row[34] for row in rows]", I have fixed that in the main post.

Comment: For sure the files are fine, I have checked each of them individually.